# Add unique group ids in group aggregate function of MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping

I wanted to add unique group ids for each group created by multiple fields in the Mongo query.

```
{ "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2 },
{ "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 },
{ "item" : "xyz", "price" : 15, "quantity" : 10 },
{ "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" :  20 },
{ "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10 }
```

I wanted to group by **items** and **price**:

```
{ "_id" : { "item" : "abc", "price" : 10 } },
{ "_id" : { "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20 } },
{ "_id" : { "item" : "xyz", "price" : 10 } },
{ "_id" : { "item" : "xyz", "price" : 15 } }
```

But along with that I wanted to add group ids for each group and the output I want:

```
{ "gid" : "1", "_id" : { "item" : "abc", "price" : 10 } },
{ "gid" : "2", "_id" : { "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20 } },
{ "gid" : "3", "_id" : { "item" : "xyz", "price" : 10 } },
{ "gid" : "4", "_id" : { "item" : "xyz", "price" : 15 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  db.collection('example').aggregate([
    {
    $group:{
        _id:{item:"$item",price:"$price"}
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            gid: {
                $function: {
                    body: function() {
                        return UUID().toString().split('"')[1];
                    },
                    args: [],
                    lang: "js"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ])
```

Comment: it will be run on python , beacuse `$function ` runs on mongodb engine

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Do you use pymongo?